# Rails generate a new layout file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I felt confused about the `Rails` layout. I have the `home` and `video` page, and I want to include their `css` and `js` relatively.

Therefore, after I used `scaffold` to create `video`, I created `video.css` and `video.js`.

Furthermore, I created a file in **view/layouts/video_layout.html.erb** and put the following code into it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Video</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'video', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'video', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    VIDEO BEGIN
    <%= yield %>
    VIDEO END
  </body>
</html>
```

I thought it will include only `video.css` and `video.js`. However, when I accessed [localhost:3000/videos](http://localhost:3000/videos), the video page was still in original condition (no `VIDEO BEGIN` and `VIDEO END` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the following line to `app/controllers/videos_controller.rb`

`layout "video_layout"`

eg

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  layout "video_layout"

  def index
  end

  ....
end
```

also check this http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Layouts.html

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, could you explain more?

Comment: Thanks, you've been a great help!